# is there a method to save data from forms django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

file models.py :

```
class Author(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    origin = JSONField(null=True)
```

file forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': '?', 'class': "input-xs form-control"}
    )
)

 class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ('full_name')
```

file  views.py :

```
 def author(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse(list_author))
```

i want to fill up the "origin" field with this dictionnairy {"data":True} ,  just in "if form.is_valid():"  , how can i do this , we must create a form field ? or we can fill up directly in if loop?

Comment: Fill it with *what*?

Comment: thnks for your response, fill it with a dictionnairy  : {"data":True}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `.origin` of the `.instance` wrapped in the form with:

```
def author(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.origin = {'data': True}
            form.save()
            return redirect('list_author')
    # …
```